# how to create a horizontal photo containor by using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a div for image along with text  summary overflow container. what to do to not make it overflow

```html
<div class="books-1" style="width:80% ;height:30%;; background-color: rgba(21, 18, 18, 0.8); border-radius: 17px;border: 2px solid;border-color: purple; margin: 2%;">
  <div class="book">

    <div class="book-info" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ; color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.721);margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;border-radius: 5px;">
      <a href="  #####novel url" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <h3 style="padding: 4%;color: white;">Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="summary" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: rgba(21, 18, 18, 0.584);width:60%;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; margin: 2%;padding: 2%; color: white;"><a href="  #####novel url" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color: white; width: 40%;">bhyxtxyrcyrcccfxxfcccccccccccxccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccf</a></div>
      <p style="padding:1%;width:40%;">by J.K. Rowling</p>
      <div class="rating" style="width: 40%;">
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 35%; float: right; line-height: normal;"><img src="lib1b1.jpg" style="width: 60%;height: 100%;border-radius: 10px;size:200%;"></div>

      <button style="padding: 3%; margin:3%;border-radius:8cap;background-color:rgb(165, 62, 224);"><a href="https://www.amazon.in/Harry-Potter-Philosophers-Stone-Rowling/dp/1408855658/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=harry+potter&qid=1621514113&sr=8-1" target="_blank" style="color: white; text-decoration: none">Read Novel</a></button>
      <button style="padding: 3%;margin:3%; border-radius:8cap;background-color:rgb(165, 62, 224);"><a href="review url" target="_blank" style="color: white; text-decoration: none">Read Review</a></button>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the text summary from overflowing, you can adjust the CSS properties of the `.summary` class. Currently, it has a fixed width, and the text-overflow properties are set to truncate the text with an ellipsis when it overflows the container.

To ensure the text doesn't overflow and stays within the specified container, you can modify the CSS of the `.summary` class.
This is an example:

```html
<div class="books-1" style="width:80%; height:30%; background-color: rgba(21, 18, 18, 0.8); border-radius: 17px; border: 2px solid; border-color: purple; margin: 2%;">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="book-info" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.721); margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%; border-radius: 5px;">
      <a href="#####novel url" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <h3 style="padding: 4%; color: white;">Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="summary" style="background-color: rgba(21, 18, 18, 0.584); white-space: normal; margin: 2%; padding: 2%; color: white;">
        <a href="#####novel url" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: white; width: 40%;   word-wrap: break-word;">
          bhyxtxyrcyrcccfxxfcccccccccccxccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccf
        </a>
      </div>
      <p style="padding: 1%; width: 40%;">by J.K. Rowling</p>
      <div class="rating" style="width: 40%;">
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
        <span>⭐</span>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 35%; float: right; line-height: normal;">
        <img src="lib1b1.jpg" style="width: 60%; height: 100%; border-radius: 10px; size: 200%;">
      </div>
      <button style="padding: 3%; margin: 3%; border-radius: 8cap; background-color: rgb(165, 62, 224);">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Harry-Potter-Philosophers-Stone-Rowling/dp/1408855658/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=harry+potter&qid=1621514113&sr=8-1" target="_blank" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Read Novel</a>
      </button>
      <button style="padding: 3%; margin: 3%; border-radius: 8cap; background-color: rgb(165, 62, 224);">
        <a href="review url" target="_blank" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">Read Review</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```